# Set up single node hortonworks hadoop cluster on Windows

Tags: windows, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I followed tutorial on Hortonworks to set up a single node cluster. However, I didn't find any guide to tell me how to finish those red parts like additional components Ranger Policy Admin etc[image]

Can any one tell me how to install this? Thanks

Comment: Can you link the tutorial you're using?

Comment: Thanks for your response. It solved by unchecked install additional components. Here is the tutorial http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0-Win/bk_QuickStart_HDPWin/content/inst_HDPWin.html

Answer (score 0):

It solved by unchecked install additional components